# Are questions about language certificates on topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, on-topic

Are questions about the existence of language skill certificates, or ways to get them, etc., on topic for the site?

Some prior questions on the main site can be found under the relevant tag: [certifications](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certifications).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing the tests and obtaining a certificate seems to be an integral part of Language Learning.

This is something to be proud of, and moreover, for some people having a certificate can be a goal by itself (e.g., for employment purposes).

So I agree with @ChristopheStrobbe, just decided to place my argumentation in a separate answer.

Answer (score 6):

I consider such questions on topic. We have had several questions like this in the past, e.g. about [certificates for Chinese that go beyond CEFR B2](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/are-there-any-advanced-proficiency-tests-for-standard-chinese-cefr-c1-c2) and [Is there a TOEFL-like exam for Italian and French languages?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3128/is-there-a-toefl-like-exam-for-italian-and-french-languages).

Comment: An argument to support this would improve the answer, but is by no means necessary.